# LINQ - Dynamic Order By Expression

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I have a little issue.  Currently, I am trying to write dynamic order by query using linq.

Sql query which i am trying to implement in linq

```
select * from tbl
order by case when Location='Loc9787f85b-c953-4238-8bad-f712b6444443' then 1 
when Location='Loc9787f85b-c953-4238-8bad-f712b6444442' then 2 end
```

Location value is is retrieved and  saved in list. It can one or more values.

This solution seems to work for static location value. Since I retrieve location value dynamically I didnt know how to implement for dynamic location value.

```
var temp = tbl.OrderBy(t => t.Location== 'Loc9787f85b-c953-4238-8bad-f712b6444443' ? 
1 : (t.Location== 'Loc9787f85b-c953-4238-8bad-f712b6444442' ? 2 : 3))
```

I will be retrieving location using this piece of code:

```
List<String> Location = CustomerService.GetAllLocation();
```

I am trying to order by using this list values. Is it possible  to implement dynamic order by using list containing column value?

Comment: I will be retrieving location using this piece of code: List<String> Location = CustomerService.GetAllLocation();
I am trying to order by using this list values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
List<String> locations = CustomerService.GetAllLocation();
var ordered =  tbl.OrderBy(t => locations.Contains(t.Location) ? 0 : 1);
```

or, if the index should represent the priority:

```
var ordered =  tbl
    .Where(t => locations.Contains(t.Location))
    .ToList() //because List.IndexOf is not supported in LINQ-TO-SQL
    .OrderBy(t => locations.IndexOf(t.Location));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. yes, index is the priority.
Solution#1 doesn't seem to implement order by properly.I get discrepancy with orders but works with linq paging.
Solution#2
This works for me. Currently, I have implemented linq paging using skip and take. 
With this code, am ending up retrieving all the rows from table and implementing order by thereafter. 
Is there any possibility to implement both order by with list of string and linq paging using skip and take?

Comment: @DuraiPandian: the first just knows 1 or 0, so you have two groups. The latter orders by the index of the item in the list. Since that is not supported by LINQ-TO-SQL i have materialized the query into a list. But since the filter is applied first the performance should be acceptable (depends on the number of matches). Skip and Take also works in LINQ-TO-Objects (so after `ToList`). I have yet not the time to search for an approach which works in database, maybe you need to insert it first into a temp table.

Comment: Thank you so much. The latter order by works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Rather push the logic out to a method like so:

```
var temp = tbl.OrderBy(t => GetOrder(t));

public int GetOrder(LocationObject t)
{
  int returnValue = 0;
  if (t.Location== "Loc9787f85b-c953-4238-8bad-f712b6444443") 
  { 
    returnValue = 1;
  }
  else if (t.Location == "Loc9787f85b-c953-4238-8bad-f712b6444442")
  {
    returnValue = 2;
  }
  else
  { 
    returnValue = 3;
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an exception "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetOrder(LocationObject)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."
Plus, I have location value in list which I am trying to loop around somewhat to generate order by query.

Comment: `LocationObject` as a type was meant as a placeholder for whatever type `t` actually is (you never specified it in your code).